# Deploy only the build artifacts of a Next.js project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, server-side-rendering, next.js

I'm trying to deploy a Next.js project using a Docker image and I was wondering if it's possible to simply use an already generated dist folder (.next) and start the next.js server (npm run start) without having to trigger the build step again in the container.

The container will be hosted in AWS Elastic Beanstalk and I also want to avoid uploading the source code and installing the npm packages there, as I already have a CI pipeline that is generating the production artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

Answering because I was going through issues with this myself and found this question. My research shows the only way to accomplish this is to run a docker environment on beanstalk and not node.js. The primary reason is that there are absolute paths in the .next build artifacts so you have to build on each instance and you have to make sure that BUILD_ID is synced across those instances.

If you CI pipeline can handle creating and pushing the Docker image, then its pretty easy to deploy on Beanstalk without any rebuilding etc. Hope that helps!

Comment: I found this post very helpful, with examples of deployment scripts you can include in your `package.json` file:  https://blog.token.ai/deploying-next-js-react-applications-to-production-sans-now-5ff014e111d0